# What do the qualifiers [0][1] do?

Tags: python, built-in

Please consider the following code which compiles and runs

```
import numpy as np

tgt = np.array([3,5,8,10,12,15])

num_guesses = 10
results =[]

for g in range(num_guesses):
    guess = np.random.uniform(low = tgt.min(), high = tgt.max())
    total_dist = np.sum((tgt-guess)**2)
    results.append((total_dist, guess))

best_guess = sorted(results)[0][1]

print(best_guess)
```

Can someone explain what the qualifiers `[0][1]` do to come up with the `best_guess` result? thanks

Comment: `results` is a list of tuples. `[0][1]` takes the second tuple index of the first row of the sorted results.

Comment: @wjandrea , yes it does thanks. I'm curious to know why the question got voted down. It was a genuine request for help.

Comment: @David Welcome! Personally, I downvoted it because it doesn't show any research. Like, what is `sorted(results)` on its own? A list. Lists support indexing, which uses square brackets, so that must be it. And its elements are tuples, which also support indexing. As well, the code is much more complicated than it needs to be. See [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `results` is a list of tuples. `[0][1]` takes the second tuple index of the first row of the sorted results.

-- [comment](/questions/68797372/#comment121584335_68797372) by [deceze ♦](/users/476/deceze)